# Как заставить Dart with angular2 работать в разных браузерах?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2

Как заставить Dart with angular2 работать в разных браузерах на локальном сервере а не только в хроме и под запуском ide или же через консоль. А чисто через локальный сервер

Это если запускать через ide[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а это если запускать через локальный сервер
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: браузеры будут запущены где? вы хотите узнать как настроить сервер для вашего приложения, что бы его было видно с любого компьютера?

Comment: нет. видно   плохо обьяснил. локалка настроина но запуск допустим ноды ток через npm run а дарта через ide. а мне надо как обычный запуск сайта

Comment: мне понятнее не стало. у вас есть сервер на nodejs? он настроен и работает? и вы хотите разместить ваше приложение на нем? добавляйте информацию в вопрос, а не в комментарии.

Comment: у меня на маке есть настроеный локальный сервер. но запустить сайт как на пхп я его не могу. что бы его запустить я прописываю npm run в консоли, для того что бы запустить дарт с ангуляром я запускаю через ide.

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.